# Can I use the same iTunes Library on both Mac OS and Windows?

Tags: itunes, bootcamp

I'm running Boot Camp, and once in a while I'd like to listen to music under Windows too. Is there a way I can use the same library under both Mac OS and Windows? Just changing the "iTunes Music" folder in Windows iTunes' preferences won't do it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have bootcamp 3.1 and install windows 7 with your bootcamp  you can do it without problem but if you installed other type of windows I recommended you read [this post](http://discussions.apple.com/thread.jspa?threadID=2309922&tstart=135).

### Edited

---

1 trick is just dragged the iTunes library into the iTunes window on my bootcamp partition and left the files where they are on the mac disk and it works just fine.

Comment: So what's the solution if I installed Boot Camp 3.1 and Windows 7?

Comment: The solution with the cmd script works best.